# Cannot deactivate powersave on screen

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, screen, embedded-linux, framebuffer

I'm working on an embedded device (based on imx6) with a Linux 3.10.17, with only a command line terminal. The Linux display works with Frame Buffer.

After 10min without activity, the screen goes black. I want it to stay ON forever.

So, I tryied the following but I got an error

```
setterm -powersave off
setterm: cannot (un)set powersave mode: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I tryied the following with another error:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
-sh: echo: write error: Input/output error
```

Finnaly, the following:

```
setterm -powerdown 0
```

There was no error, but after 10min, the screen goes off.

I could not figure if the problem come from the Linux config file, from the driver, the device tree. Does anybody can help me fixing one of the previous command, or gave me another solution.

Answer (score 1):

From `linux/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt`:

```
consoleblank=   [KNL] The console blank (screen saver) timeout in
                seconds. Defaults to 10*60 = 10mins. A value of 0
                disables the blank timer.
```

So, just add `consoleblank=0` to your kernel command line.